# Get the incoming request header from IIS into my angular app

Tags: angular, http, iis, http-headers

So I have an existing angular 7 web application (let's call this **myapp**) which runs on IIS (App Service) hosted in Azure.

There is a legacy application (let's call this **theirapp**), with it's own embedded browser, which will load our application by navigating to myapp's url.

When theirapp loads myapp, theirapp passes some information in the header something like `Request.headers.SpecificThingMyAppNeeds`

I need to be able to access this request.headers in **myapp**.

Thank you all!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184107/read-response-headers-from-api-response-angular-5-typescript/48184742

Comment: Hi @Karthick, i dont think it's a duplicate. myapp doesn't make the request. it gets loaded from a browser

Comment: What do you mean by gets loaded from browser?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan Client1 has a winform application with an embedded IE11. Client1 launches their embedded IE11 to browse my webapp via https://myapp.com. 
Client1's browser sends extra information in the header when it browses myapp.

Comment: @jmesolomon  Your Application is running in the browser, so your application doesn't receive any requests, but the browser does. you could refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984914/how-to-get-request-header-value-when-accessing-my-angular-application

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thanks! you are correct. I think the solution is to change our architecture. Regards

Comment: @jmesolomon if my solution helps you then I request you to mark the post as an answer it will help other people. thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is running in the browser, so your application doesn't receive any requests, but the browser does. you could refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984914/how-to-get-request-header-value-when-accessing-my-angular-application)