# How to get a request header value on an Angular Component?

Tags: angular, typescript, chromium-embedded

I have two applications, the first one is Angular and will receive a get request with a value in the header request. This request will be sent by the second application (a chromiumwebbrowser inside windows forms, to use the angular component built-in).
My question is, how can I get the value of a header property when my angular components is started?
I know I can pass the values using a query parameter, in the url and get it using the routes, but I'm trying to use the headers to avoid security issues and don't expose the value.

[image: Header property i need to get in angular]

Comment: Can you show the part of code where "Angular [...] will receive a get request"... On which platform is this "Angular application" running?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984914/how-to-get-request-header-value-when-accessing-my-angular-application may help

Comment: What you’re showing in the screenshot seems to be the browser requesting something from the server (with a GET). Usually an angular application running in the browser never receives requests. Everything is always initiated by the browser..

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, MikeOne. I solved using an url query parameter, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the MikeOne explanation, I thinked about this, so I solved using a query parameter in the url and getting it using the routes.